# How do I change colour of icon font inside active tab?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm trying to get the colour of my icon to stay a certain colour when it's the open active tab, but it's not working. I've been able to use p:active to get the icons to change colour when clicked, but that colour goes away after the click is done. I'd like it to stay when that tab is open.

The button.active is working only for background color and not font color. Can anyone help figure this out? I'm at a loss.

Here is all my coding:

```
/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
overflow: hidden;
border: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
background-color:transparent;
float: center;
border: none;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
min-width:100px;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 16px;
color:white;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height:1;
margin: 2%;
height:31px;
font-weight:300;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button > p:hover {
color:black;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
background-color:#F7941D;
color:white;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
display: none;
padding: 6px 12px;
border: 0px;
border-top: none;
text-align:center;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="USA" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
<img class="diagram" src="http://dev.legendpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Diagram_usa.png" style="margin-bottom:2%;">
</div>

<div id="Canada" class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
<img class="diagram" src="http://dev.legendpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Diagram_can.png"style="margin-bottom:2%;">
</div>

<div class="tab" style="width:50%; height:50px;">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openToggle(event, 'USA')" id="defaultOpen"><p class="icon-usa-flag-icon" id="defaultOpen"></p></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openToggle(event, 'Canada')"><p class="icon-canada-flag-icon-1"></p></button>
</div>

</div></div>
```

And the JS I'm using:

```
function openToggle(evt, ToggleName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
document.getElementById(ToggleName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Comment: but your active button text is empty?!?! or did you miss something in the code above. the color style will affect text inside the button and p.

Comment: I don't want any text there, just the icon which I put in through using class="icon-usa-flag-icon", etc.

Comment: whats the style for the "icon-usa-flag-icon" element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `p` tag with the icon class and change the color, so instead of this :

```
div.tab button.active {
    background-color:#F7941D;
    color:white;
}
```

you should do this :

```
div.tab button.active {
    background-color:#F7941D;
}

div.tab button.active p[class|="icon"] {
    color:white;
}
```

I used this attribute selector `[class|="icon"]` to target all your icons since all of them start with the word **icon**. You can read more about [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Comment: So what exactly would the coding be for that? the p class is "icon-usa-flag-icon"... is that what I put where you wrote 'icon'?

Comment: @JillSlattery i gave you the exact coding :) `p[class|="icon"]` will target all p that have class start with **icon** so it will work with all icons, have a try and see the result ;)

Comment: @JillSlattery what i used is called attribute selector, you can read more here : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. My styling of the icons was overriding the styling I had for the button, which was causing the issue.

Comment: it's not an issue, this is called specifity. That's why in my answer i told you to target the p tag and not the button as this selector will be more specific and can override the default icon option.